# How get path absolute of a vendor in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and FOSJsRoutingBundle, and I need to indicate the absolute path in the next src:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

I am using KnpSnappyBundle and this path fails. With "asset" I have had to use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `url` instead of `path`. As Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

More info in the TWIG reference [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/twig_reference.html).

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks @Matteo, I had forgotten that. Anyway, I still giving error when using the Bundle KnpSnappyBundle, I thought there would be other way to put with request as in the case of asset.